# Backbone.js and codeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, backbone.js

I'm using the [codeigniter](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter) Framework to use my servers side logic, and I want to use [backbonejs](http://backbonejs.org/) to manage the client side logic.

I read a lot about it and there are many ways to achieve this, I thought using the following design:

- In **CI** , keep only one view for each application. This will be a placeholder for the content that will be pushed by **BackboneJS**. The **BackboneJS** will be loaded from this page.
- In **BackboneJS**, manage all the application client side , and query the **CI** controllers (that might call **CI** models if needed) to fetch the dynamic content.

What is the best way to use them both? Does my design breaks the **MVC** design somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Premise: I use Yii instead of CI but I think they work in a similar way.

I have a index view in Yii which contains the main HTML structure of my app (menu, sidebar, main content, etc.) and a main controller which manage the REST requests, using Yii's model to retrieve information.

On the client Backbone take care of all, each route fire a request to the REST-like api and the views are finally rendered by the client with the data returned from the server in JSON format.

I don't know if this is the better way, but after some struggling I get it to work and I'm quite happy about it.